# why does 'del' in python deletes original source of created array?

Tags: python

Below I define an array 'x' based on 'response'. Then I modify 'x' using python's del if certain condition is met regarding the 'data' array. Why is 'response' also modified in the same way 'x' is?

```
response = {'result': [{'input_1':[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 'input_2': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [5, 3], [0, 0]]},
                       {'input_1':[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 'input_2': [[0, 0], [6, 7], [0, 0], [0, 0]]},
                       {'input_1':[[0, 0], [2, 5], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 'input_2': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [5, 3], [0, 0]]},
                       {'input_1':[[0, 0], [0, 0], [5, 1], [0, 0]], 'input_2': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]},
                       {'input_1':[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 'input_2': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [5, 3], [0, 0]]},
                       {'input_1':[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 'input_2': [[0, 0], [6, 7], [0, 0], [0, 0]]},
                       {'input_1':[[0, 0], [2, 5], [0, 0], [0, 0]], 'input_2': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [5, 3], [0, 0]]}],
            'something_else': [1,2,3]}
```

```
x = []
for my_dict in response['result']:
    x.append(my_dict['input_1'])
    x.append(my_dict['input_2'])
```

```
data =  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
for i, bit in enumerate(x):
    if data[i] == 0:
        del x[i][0:2]
        print(x[i])
```

I printed to console both 'x' and 'response' after running the conditional for loop and they are the same. I wasn't expecting that because only 'x' is being deleted if the condition is met. Why is 'response' also modified instead of only 'x'?

Comment: Are are putting references to arrays in `x` not copies. `x[0] is response['result'][0]['input_1']` will be `True` because they both refer to the same array in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `x.append(my_dict['input_1'])` is first executed, `x[0]` and `my_dict['input_1']` point to *the same object*.

If this isn't what you want, you can use <s>`list()`</s> `deepcopy()` to create a new list in memory:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

for my_dict in response["result"]:
    x.append(deepcopy(my_dict["input_1"]))
    x.append(deepcopy(my_dict["input_2"]))
```

Comment: They're nested lists, so you'll probably want to actually do a [deep copy](//docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), though OP's code doesn't modify the interior lists.